# Remote Desktop Licensing mode is not configured in Windows Server2012

Tags: remote-desktop, licensing, windows-server-2012

Usualy I use RDP in Windows Server 2008 R2, and never fall in this: "Remote Desktop Licensing mode is not configured", This is a message that I get as soon as I open session in the newly installed Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Is it necessary to configure license for Remote desktop in spite I am the unique RDP user?

I noticed that by default Windows Server 2012 added automaticaly Remote Desktop services and Remote Desktop session Host, when I added The RDP role in server manager snap-in. Is it necessary to keep all these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only using RDP to manage the server then you don't need any of the RDS roles or services. Remote Desktop (for managing the server) uses the RDP protocol just like RDS does, but it's not neccessary to add the RDS roles. the RDP protocol is built in to the OS and remote management via RDP is enabled in the Local Server settings in Server Manager.

Comment: You saved me from the confusion that was in my mind, Could you please give an idea on what is RDS feature, and to what it serves beside RDP?

Comment: RDS (Remote Desktop Services) allows for multiple users (more than two) to log on to the server concurrently for the purpose of using the server as a desktop for running applications (such as Microsoft Office, etc.). RDS requires RDS CAL's (client access licenses) and requires an RDS License server. Remote Desktop for managing the server (up to two concurrent connections) doesn't require the RDS role or RDS CAL's or an RDS License server.

Comment: Thank you very much joeqwerty, now I am posting this question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/445100/protected-object-this-object-on-the-rompager-server-is-protected