# Getting authentication window when browsing web sites on my server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, adsl

I have a windows home server. When I browse from the net any web site in it I get an authentication window with the next message: "http://mydomain.com site requires user name and password, the site says: "SmartAX". Then when I close the window I get an error page saying:

Protected object

this object on the rompager server is protected

Could you please help on this, have it relation with ADSL router ?

Comment: "Anything in the home" is specifically excluded in our [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some routers might redirect you to their admin interface page when there're problems with the internet connection. Make sure that your internet connection is up.
To check if your connection is up try to ping any address e.g.
start->cmd->ping google.com

Comment: Yesterday I could browse the default website and got the correct IIS default web page using the same router, and currently I succeeded to ping google.com as you advised to verify connection, I have rebooted the router to see if any cached data, the result is that the issue is still persisting.

Comment: Can you browse other pages without a problem?

Comment: No, since this is the first thing that appears.

Comment: Press escape key and type other url, e.g. www.google.com

Comment: Escape key removes the window and www.google.com send to google web site without problem.

Comment: Change the default page to "www.google.com" in your browser and see if that problem still occurs. There might be some issues with your adsl router - disabling content filtering (parental filtering) on your router might help.